# How to add IDPs to OpenAM federation via CREST API?

Tags: saml-2.0, openam, federation

I know that there are REST APIs for OpenAM for some functions like self service, authentication etc.., But I'm not able to find the right apis for adding remote identity provider etc..,

Either I'm missing something or there is no such REST apis for OpenAM due to some reason. The reason could be they are not planning on it, or it's not yet there in the current release.

Is there any way I can register the SAML IDPs in OpenAM without using OpenAM admin console or `ssoadm` command?

Pointers to the right code components will also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access Manager 5 (OpenAM 14) you can manage SAML entities using the REST APIs. To create a new hosted SAMLv2 IdP you will need something like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/json/realm-config/federation/entityproviders/saml2?_action=create' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'iplanetdirectorypro: <ADMIN_SESSION_ID>' \
  -d '{
      "_id": "http://idp.example.com:8080/openam",
      "metadata": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<EntityDescriptor entityID=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam\" xmlns=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata\">\n    <IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned=\"false\" protocolSupportEnumeration=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol\">\n        <KeyDescriptor use=\"signing\">\n            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">\n                <ds:X509Data>\n                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDaDCCAlCgAwIBAgIDcB/YMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVLMRAwDgYDVQQIEwdCcmlzdG9sMRAwDgYDVQQHEwdCcmlzdG9sMRIwEAYDVQQKEwlGb3JnZVJvY2sxDzANBgNVBAsTBk9wZW5BTTENMAsGA1UEAxMEdGVzdDAeFw0xNjAzMTgxMTU2MjhaFw0yNjAzMTYxMTU2MjhaMGUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVLMRAwDgYDVQQIEwdCcmlzdG9sMRAwDgYDVQQHEwdCcmlzdG9sMRIwEAYDVQQKEwlGb3JnZVJvY2sxDzANBgNVBAsTBk9wZW5BTTENMAsGA1UEAxMEdGVzdDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAKNbl89eP6B8kZATNSPe3+OZ3esLx31hjX+dakHtPwXCAaCKqJFwjwKdxyRuPdsVG+8Dbk3PGhk26aJrSE93EpxeqmQqxNPMeD+N0/8pjkuVYWwPIQ/ts2iTiWOVn7wzlE4ASfvupqOR5pjuYMWNo/pd4L7QNjUCKoAt9H11HMyiP+6roo/EYgX4AH7OAhfUMncYsopWhkW/ze9z8wTXc8BAEgDmt8zFCez1CtqJB/MlSBUGDgk8oHYDsHKmx05baBaOBQ8LRGP5SULSbRtu34eLFootBIn0FvUZSnwTiSpbaHHRgWrMOVm07oSLWBuO3h/bj38zBuuqqVsAK8YuyoECAwEAAaMhMB8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFHxfAbr6PQ5Xgc+jVx+AGTPnnpWZMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQAZBMJ29/2idv1ztC6ArHtB4kw/nHHwthXFwtWAN7sRPB8tLW7fD8aJ43RQr5107Bg1Lgkmt+FZxpafqUC/mukjIzGzbW0COMSOTcWUGss+HxK6M6Fl9aOzKJMct1uOSpPFgjItcGqydGZXR2FH93vXWoAotUwtZ119IixIdxpOJwYJg0HFn+GEfpU1PmiLfq2/uwqJ0hGCNfNcm9puagzhQrcDFOnolxjnYPSfSkU5wxlGo99yE5eJwoHXXU7csaZVttmx7sPj1lUENogXUM6JMqzSyEIm1XCOCL8rZJkZ781W5CwZhuJTNzV31sBREs8FaaCeksu7Y48BmkUqw6E9</ds:X509Certificate>\n                </ds:X509Data>\n            </ds:KeyInfo>\n        </KeyDescriptor>\n        <ArtifactResolutionService index=\"0\" isDefault=\"true\" Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/ArtifactResolver/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <SingleLogoutService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/IDPSloRedirect/metaAlias/idp\" ResponseLocation=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/IDPSloRedirect/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <SingleLogoutService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/IDPSloPOST/metaAlias/idp\" ResponseLocation=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/IDPSloPOST/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <SingleLogoutService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/IDPSloSoap/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <ManageNameIDService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/IDPMniRedirect/metaAlias/idp\" ResponseLocation=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/IDPMniRedirect/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <ManageNameIDService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/IDPMniPOST/metaAlias/idp\" ResponseLocation=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/IDPMniPOST/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <ManageNameIDService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/IDPMniSoap/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</NameIDFormat>\n        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat>\n        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>\n        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</NameIDFormat>\n        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:WindowsDomainQualifiedName</NameIDFormat>\n        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:kerberos</NameIDFormat>\n        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</NameIDFormat>\n        <SingleSignOnService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <SingleSignOnService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/SSOPOST/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <SingleSignOnService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/SSOSoap/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <NameIDMappingService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/NIMSoap/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <AssertionIDRequestService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/AIDReqSoap/IDPRole/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n        <AssertionIDRequestService Binding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:URI\" Location=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/AIDReqUri/IDPRole/metaAlias/idp\"/>\n    </IDPSSODescriptor>\n</EntityDescriptor>\n\n",
      "entityConfig": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<EntityConfig entityID=\"http://idp.example.com:8080/openam\" hosted=\"true\" xmlns=\"urn:sun:fm:SAML:2.0:entityconfig\">\n    <IDPSSOConfig metaAlias=\"/idp\">\n        <Attribute name=\"description\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"signingCertAlias\">\n            <Value>test</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"encryptionCertAlias\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"basicAuthOn\">\n            <Value>false</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"basicAuthUser\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"basicAuthPassword\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"autofedEnabled\">\n            <Value>false</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"autofedAttribute\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"assertionEffectiveTime\">\n            <Value>600</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"idpAuthncontextMapper\">\n            <Value>com.sun.identity.saml2.plugins.DefaultIDPAuthnContextMapper</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"idpAuthncontextClassrefMapping\">\n            <Value>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport|0||default</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"idpAccountMapper\">\n            <Value>com.sun.identity.saml2.plugins.DefaultIDPAccountMapper</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"idpDisableNameIDPersistence\">\n            <Value>false</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"idpAttributeMapper\">\n            <Value>com.sun.identity.saml2.plugins.DefaultIDPAttributeMapper</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"assertionIDRequestMapper\">\n            <Value>com.sun.identity.saml2.plugins.DefaultAssertionIDRequestMapper</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"nameIDFormatMap\">\n            <Value>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress=mail</Value>\n            <Value>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName=</Value>\n            <Value>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:WindowsDomainQualifiedName=</Value>\n            <Value>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:kerberos=</Value>\n            <Value>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified=</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"idpECPSessionMapper\">\n            <Value>com.sun.identity.saml2.plugins.DefaultIDPECPSessionMapper</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"attributeMap\"/>\n        <Attribute name=\"wantNameIDEncrypted\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"wantArtifactResolveSigned\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"wantLogoutRequestSigned\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"wantLogoutResponseSigned\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"wantMNIRequestSigned\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"wantMNIResponseSigned\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"cotlist\">\n            <Value>test</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"discoveryBootstrappingEnabled\">\n            <Value>false</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"assertionCacheEnabled\">\n            <Value>false</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"assertionNotBeforeTimeSkew\">\n            <Value>600</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"saeAppSecretList\"/>\n        <Attribute name=\"saeIDPUrl\">\n            <Value>http://idp.example.com:8080/openam/idpsaehandler/metaAlias/idp</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"AuthUrl\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"appLogoutUrl\">\n            <Value/>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"idpSessionSyncEnabled\">\n            <Value>false</Value>\n        </Attribute>\n        <Attribute name=\"relayStateUrlList\"/>\n    </IDPSSOConfig>\n</EntityConfig>\n\n",
      "_type": {
        "_id": "saml2",
        "name": "Entity Descriptor ",
        "collection": true
      }
    }'
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it documented?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the endpoint should be present in the API explorer.